# Summate opacity for AnglePath

Tags: graphics, opacity

I explore substitutions systems and use `AnglePath` visualization as an analogue of turtle graphics. I’d like to have the effect:
*the lines that are visited more frequently are more bright.*
For example, for Julia+Luxor it is enough to set `setopacity(0.1)` and get this image:

[image]

Here is the same process that is seen on WM with `AnglePath`. The process itself is identical, but the image is not the same:

[image]

And in simple examples you can see that in `AnglePath` summing opacity does not work!

```
Graphics[{White, Opacity[0.5], Thickness[0.02], 
  Line[AnglePath[ConstantArray[110 °, 20]]]}, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

At the same time for simple graphics works:

```
Graphics[{White, Opacity[0.5], Thickness[0.02], 
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]}, 
 Background -> Black]
```

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately all answers are either limited or give unnecessary artefacts.
So I did it myself.
Prepare process:

```
mainProc[r_, n_] := Nest[SequenceReplace[#, r] &, r[[1, 1]], n];
(*Just for example, but it's interesting rule*)
rule = {{0} -> Sequence[0, 1], {1, 1} -> Sequence[0, 0]};
num = 20; ang = \[Pi]/3.;
path = AnglePath[ang mainProc[rule, num]];
```

Because it's turtle graphics, *we can* round up data up to half of step,
but *only for to find polylines!*

```
rawPath = Round[path, .5];
```

Here is an algorithm that finds all the repetitions of lines
(and find max count for to calculate correct opacity).
For sure it can be improved, but it works =)

```
k = 2; L = Length@rawPath;
data = Reap[
    While[k < L,
     j = 0; tmp = rawPath[[1 ;; k - 1]];
     While[k + j <= L && MemberQ[tmp, rawPath[[k + j]]],
      j += 1];
     If[j > 1, Sow[Range[k, k + j - 1], 1];Sow[rawPath[[k]], 2]];
     k = k + j + 1
     ]][[2]];
```

Substitute exact coordinates and find correct opacity:

```
lines = path[[#]] & /@ data[[1]];
opac = 1./(Max[Tally[data[[2]]][[All, 2]]] + 1.)
```

And here it is, fast enough, but not for `Manipulate` certainly =(

```
Graphics[{LightBlue, Thickness@0.005, Opacity@opac,
  Line@path, Line /@ lines}, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

[image]

BONUS. If we replace

```
If[j > 1, Sow...];
```

to

```
If[j > 0, Sow...];
```

we can get summation of opacity on intersections,
what is may be useful:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For an example, we first create a path:

```
SeedRandom[1];
path = AnglePath[RandomChoice[Pi {1/2, -1/2}, 100]] // Round;
```

Then we create the different lines of this path. We do not want the direction the line is traveled to matter and therefore sort the lines:

```
lines = Sort /@ Partition[path, 2, 1];
```

Next we count how many times a line appears and get the maximum count:

```
tmp = Tally[lines];
ma = Max[tmp[[All, 2]]];
```

To get the opacity, we create an association that associates an opacity value with every line:

```
opac = AssociationThread[tmp[[All, 1]] -> tmp[[All, 2]]/ma];
```

Now we are ready to create the graphics:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[opac[#]], Line[#]} & /@ lines]
```

[image]

For convenience, here is all together:

```
SeedRandom[1];
path = AnglePath[RandomChoice[Pi {1/2, -1/2}, 100]] // Round;
lines = Sort /@ Partition[path, 2, 1];
tmp = Tally[lines];
ma = Max[tmp[[All, 2]]];
opac = AssociationThread[tmp[[All, 1]] -> tmp[[All, 2]]/ma];
Graphics[{Opacity[opac[#]], Line[#]} & /@ lines]
```

Comment: `Round` not work cause points are reals. And `Tally` not work cause in the sense of opacity `Line[{{0,0},{1,1}}]` the same as  `Line[{{1,1},{0,0}}]`

Comment: If you work with machine numbers you will have problems identifying lines because of small errors. At least you must use rationals. The problem of direction is taken into account  by "Sort"

Answer (score 1):

A decent result can be achieved with simple code using `VertexColors` although there is still a little overlap at each hinge of the path.

```
Graphics[{Thickness[0.005], 
  Line[path, 
   VertexColors -> 
    Table[Directive[Lighter[Cyan], Opacity[0.5]], Length[path]]]}, 
 Background -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: wow looks very cool! And lightweight code.
I need some experiments